# how to apply elasticsearch using python on files in azure-data-lake?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, azure-data-lake

I have uploaded files in azure data lake by python in gen1. Those files, which exist in azure data lake, I need to apply elastic search to those files (the files can be .pdf, .csv, .xlsx, .doc.) using python django.

Comment: You need to describe better what you want to do. What do you mean by 'apply elasticsearch?' Elasticsearch is a search engine, you store documents in it, you don't use it to search on files outside of its storage.

Comment: I mean that already in my azure data lake account, I have stored my files. For that files I need to apply elastic search, by that whenever I try to retrieve the file or if I try to search any word in my project, I need to get the information from that files , That how many times the word in there in my files.

Comment: Elasticsearch does not work that way, it does not search on files, you need to index the contents of your documents in elasticsearch to be able to search for it, you need a elasticsearch cluster and some way to ingest the content of the files in elasticsearch.

Comment: okay thank you, I meant to say that I need to create a index. so can u help me how we can do it. please

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://www.dremio.com/tutorials/adls-dremio-qlik/) helps you to index and query large amounts of structured data by combining ADLS and Elasticsearch using third-party tool called Dremio.

**About Dremio:** Dremio provides a self-service semantic layer and governance for your data. Dremio’s semantic layer is an integrated, searchable catalog in the Data Graph that indexes all of your metadata, allowing business users to easily make sense of the data in the data lake. Anything created by users—spaces, directories, and virtual datasets make up the semantic layer, all of which is indexed and searchable. The relationships between your data sources, virtual datasets, and all your queries are also maintained in the Data Graph, creating a data lineage, allowing you to govern and maintain your data.

Azure Data Lake Store is a highly scalable and secure data storage and analytics service that deals with big data problems easily. It provides a variety of functions and solutions for data management and governance.

Elasticsearch is a powerful search and analytics engine. It is highly popular due to the scale-out architecture, JSON data model, and text search capabilities. Also, with the help of Elasticsearch, you can index and query large amounts of structured data, use convenient RESTful API, and more.

Hope this helps.